Prove point $D$, point $B$, and point $N$ are collinear
Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $M$ a point on $\overline{BC}$, $N$ a point on $\overline{CA}$, and $P$ a point on $\overline{AB}$ such that $2BM=BC$, $2NC=AN$, and $3PB=AP$. Prove that the midpoint of $\overline{MP}$ and point $B$ and point $N$ are collinear.
Let us denote the midpoint of $\overline{MP}$ as $D$.
We know that $BM=\frac{1}{2}BC$, $AN=\frac{2}{3}AC$, and $AP=\frac{3}{4}AB$.
I'm unsure if the Midpoint Theorem can play a role in solving this, as I see no direct application of it. In fact, I'm completely stumped on how to even continue! Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Do you accept a proof using vectors? This proposition does not depend on angles ($\angle ABC$ is arbitrary), therefore using vectors might be simpler. Or do you prefer pure geometry?

I believe any sort of proof is fine.

Do you know how vectors work? A proof using vectors should be pretty quick

Yes, I have a decent understanding of vectors.

Did you try proving $\angle BDN = 180 ^{\circ}$?

The linear algebra proof is great, but Miss Geometry will feel bad if I don't use her in her own thing.
Please refer to my diagram:-

You also need to know a basic area law which I'm going to use a lot here. In simple words, if height($h$)=constant, then
$$\frac{Area_1}{Area_2}=\frac{b_1}{b_2} $$
Now let's begin with the problem. I have assumed midpoint of $MP$ as $D$. I will reach a statement assuming the fact that $B,D,N$ are collinear.
As $AP=3BP,Ar{\triangle APN}=3\ Ar{\triangle BPN}$
Hence $Ar{\triangle ABN}=Ar{\triangle APN}+Ar{\triangle BPN}=4 \ Ar{\triangle BPN}$
Now
$$Ar{\triangle BPD}=Ar{\triangle BMD}\ [X \ \text{is midpoint}]...(i)$$
$$Ar{\triangle NPD}=Ar{\triangle NMD}\ [X \ \text{is midpoint}]...(ii)$$
$$(i)+(ii)\ \text{gives} \ Ar{\triangle BPN}=Ar{\triangle BMN}...(iii)$$
But $$Ar{\triangle BMN}=Ar{\triangle MNC}\ [M \ \text{is midpoint}]\implies 2\ Ar{\triangle BMN}= Ar{\triangle BMN}+Ar{\triangle MNC}=Ar{\triangle BNC}$$
From $(iii),2 \ Ar{\triangle BPN}= Ar {\triangle BNC}$
So$$ \frac{Ar{\triangle ABN}}{Ar \triangle BNC}= \frac{4\ Ar \triangle BPN}{2 \ Ar \triangle BPN} = 2$$
Now we verify the fact using the data $2 \ NC = AN$. Using the formula I stated above, $Ar \triangle ABN = 2 \ Ar \triangle BNC$. This proves what we had found above. Hence $B,D,N$ are collinear.

Here is a proof using vectors.
First we translate conditions into formulae:

$2BM=BC \implies \overrightarrow{BM} = \frac12 \overrightarrow{BC}$.
$2NC=AN \implies \overrightarrow{CN} = \frac13 \overrightarrow{CA} \implies \overrightarrow{BN} = \frac23 \overrightarrow{BC} + \frac13 \overrightarrow{BA}$. (Hint: $\overrightarrow{CN} = \overrightarrow{BN} - \overrightarrow{BC}$.)
$3PB=AP \implies \overrightarrow{BP} = \frac14 \overrightarrow{BA}$.

And $D$ is the midpoint of $\overline{MP} \implies \overrightarrow{BD} = \frac12 \overrightarrow{BM} + \frac12 \overrightarrow{BP} = \frac14 \overrightarrow{BC} + \frac18 \overrightarrow{BA}$.
Now we represent all three points ($B,D,N$) in combinations of $\overrightarrow{BA}$ and $\overrightarrow{BC}$.
Note that $\overrightarrow{BD} = \frac14 \overrightarrow{BC} + \frac18 \overrightarrow{BA} = \frac38 (\frac23 \overrightarrow{BC} + \frac13 \overrightarrow{BA}) = \frac38 \overrightarrow{BN}$, so $\overline{BD} \parallel \overline{BN}$, thus $B,D,N$ are collinear.

How is it possible that $\overline{BD}\parallel \overline{BN}$?

Because $\overrightarrow{BD}$ is a multiple of $\overrightarrow{BN}$. (Formally, $\exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}, \overrightarrow{BD} = \lambda \overrightarrow{BN}$.) @DavidMa

We already have good answers, but i decided to also post one, since the problem is one inside projective geometry, and it deserves also a quick solution of this kind, using theorems like Ceva and Menelaus.
Consider the following picture,
which introduces the points $N_1,E\in AC$, such that $AN_1=N_1C=CE$.

(So $N_1$ is the mid point of $AC$.)
Then the points $P,M,E$ are collinear, (reciprocal of) Menelaus for $\Delta ABC$ w.r.t. to these points, since:
$$
\frac{PA}{PB}\cdot
\frac{MB}{MC}\cdot
\frac{EC}{EA}
=
\left(-\frac 31\right)\cdot
\left(-\frac 11\right)\cdot
\left(+\frac 13\right)
=1\ .
$$
Because of $N_1M\|APB$ we have
$PM:PE=AN_1:AE=1:3$. So the position of $D$ on $AE$ is so that $PD:PE=1:6$.
Which is the position of $N$ on $AE$? Denoting
$AC$ by $6x$ we have $AN_1=N_1C=CE=3x$ and $NC=2x$, so $AN:NE=(4x):(5x)$.
This allows to apply again (the reciprocal of) Menelaus' Theorem for $\Delta ABE$ w.r.t. the points $B,D,N$ on its sides:
$$
\frac {DP}{DE}\cdot  
\frac {NE}{NA}\cdot  
\frac {BA}{BP}
=
\left(-\frac 15\right)\cdot
\left(-\frac 54\right)\cdot
\left(+\frac 41\right)
=1\ ,
$$
so the points $B,D,N$ are collinear.

I just had a little box written in my geometry book about Melenaus' theorem, with no practical uses of it. This proof is great. I've never seen this theorem being used before. +1
